# How To Fix syntax error unexpected token < , On jQuery.ajaxFileUpload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, file-upload

**This is my Jquery code**

```
function kirimgambar(chatboxtitle) {

    var file = jQuery( ".pilih" ).val();
    if(file==""){ 
    jQuery("#chatboxtextarea").focus();
    }else {
    jQuery("#loading")
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        jQuery(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxComplete(function(){
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });

    jQuery.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'http://localhost:8080/diobatin/application/views/chat/chat.php?action=kirimfile',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{name:'logan', id:'id', chatboxtitle:chatboxtitle},
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(data.error != '')
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }else
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e); //This ouput is "syntax error unexpected token <"
            }
        }
    )
    chatHeartbeatTime = minChatHeartbeat;
    chatHeartbeatCount = 1;
    return false;   
    }
```

}

**And in chat.php is**

```
    function kirimfile() {
    $error = "";
    $msg = "";
    $fileElementName = 'fileToUpload';
    if(!empty($_FILES[$fileElementName]['error']))
    {
        $error = 'No file was uploaded..';
    }elseif(empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) || $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] == 'none')
    {
        $error = 'No file was uploaded..';
    }else 
    {
            $upload_path = "./asset/";
            if (!is_dir($upload_path)) {
                mkdir($upload_path);
            } 

             $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
             $tmp  = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
                // jika $file ada dan tidak kosong
                if ((isset($file)) && ($file != "")) { 
                    // handle apabila sudah ada file sama yang terupload, maka akan dibuat copynya
                    $uploadfile = (file_exists($upload_path.$file)) ? $upload_path." copy of ".$file : $upload_path.$file;
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $uploadfile);
                    if (chmod($uploadfile, 0775)) {
                        $from = $_SESSION['username'];
                        $to = $_POST['chatboxtitle'];
                        $message =  $_SESSION['username'];
                        $messagesan = sanitize($message);

    if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']])) {
        $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] = '';
    }

    $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] .= <<<EOD
                       {
            "s": "1",
            "f": "{$to}",
            "m": "{$messagesan}"
       },
EOD;
    unset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']]);          

                        }
            }
    }
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
    echo "{\n";
    echo                "error: '" . $error . "',\n";
    echo                "msg: '" . $msg . "'\n";
    echo "}";
}
```

This output return on alern is **syntax error unexpected token <** in **chrome**
But in **mozilla firefox** Erro reporting is ***The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.***

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` is not `JSON`, you don't need it anyway.

Comment: You can do it like `$arr = array('error'=>$error,'msg'=>$msg); echo json_encode($arr);`.

Comment: Yes I try delete this echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'; but no change, is same this output is "syntax error unexpected token <"

Comment: Try with the answer below :)

Comment: also if your returning json, your content-type should be `application/json` ... (not that it should be set as part of the output, but as `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` and `\n` is not JSON.

Replace

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
echo "{\n";
echo                "error: '" . $error . "',\n";
echo                "msg: '" . $msg . "'\n";
echo "}";
```

With

```
$arr = array(
            'error' => $error,
            'msg'   => $msg
        ); 

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: this is same =
in  mozilla is output is == The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.

Comment: Is the php bit works fine? I mean does it do uploads without ajax? If I were you I wud do that first. May be php is generating an error which is printed out and returned to the ajax request.

Comment: Upload php run correctly. but when I remove this code -> ..

 if (!isset($_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']])) {
  $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] = '';
 }
 
 $_SESSION['chatHistory'][$_POST['to']] .= <<<EOD
        {
   "s": "1",
   "f": "{$to}",
   "m": "{$messagesan}"
    },
EOD;
 unset($_SESSION['tsChatBoxes'][$_POST['to']]); 

Results out jquery is true.

Comment: check if `$_POST['to']` exists first and also check if session is started.

Comment: Yes you are right. 
$_POST['to']  is wrong , true is $_POST['chatboxtitle']
Thank you very much. You are very smart

Comment: Good. I am glad that I was of any help :)